# Most Rubyish Way To Get An Array Containing Specific Values From An Array Of Objects?

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have an array of ruby objects that looks something like this:

```
[#<email: "someemail" other_properties: "SDFDF">, #<...>, #<...>]
```

Each of the objects in the array has an `email` property. I want to get a new array of all the email properties of the ruby objects in the array.

After executing the code, I would have an array that looked like this:

```
["email@example.com", "anotheremail@gmail.com", ...]
```

I am newer to ruby and want to do this in the most rubyish way possible.

My question is, what's the best way to do this in ruby?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the [`map`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000249) method to apply a block to each element of the array, returning a new array containing the results of each invocation:

```
somearray.map {|x| x.email}
```

Comment: Thank you! This exactly what I was after. I will accept as soon as SO lets me. :)

Comment: In Ruby 1.87+ you can simplify this as `somearray.map(&:email)`